# Как создать всплывающее окно в Puppeteer?

Tags: node.js, popup, puppeteer

Subj. Два часа бьюсь. Нужно, чтобы при выполнении условия появлялся popup, как в Autohotkey - <MsgBox, "Привет!">. Puppeteer увидел только сегодня.

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Message Box. Как создать Message Box в node.js, puppetter и вот в этом всём. В Autohotkey это банально просто и элементарно - MsgBox, текст. Появляется ... Message Box с текстом. Можно нажать Ок, можно задать время жизни, он сам исчезнет. Message Box. В Puppetter.